# I can't open Ubuntu after a wubi install

Tags: ubuntu-netbook

I can't open Ubuntu after the wubi install or with the CD, the white bar just keeps blinking but nothing happens. I have a MSI vr602 laptop.

Comment: Try the steps here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it